# Powershell - Remove Expired Certs Before Todays Date

Tags: powershell

I am trying to script a removal of certs issued by 'Microsoft Intune MDM Device CA' with an expiry date that has expired.

My code so far only brings back a list of certs in this directory but not sure how i can script the above? Any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
$today = Get-Date
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My
Where-Object After -lt $today

Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Select-Object NotAfter, Subject
```

the above script does not show me expired certs! I want it to show me expired certs under the name 'Microsoft Intune MDM Device CA' and then proceed to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all expired certificates.

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -ExpiringInDays 0 -Recurse | Select-Object Thumbprint, Subject, NotAfter | Format-List
```

ExpiringInDays 0 parameter gets certificates for computers that have expired.

Remove certificates by using Thumbprint

```
Remove-Item Cert:\LocalMachine\My\0E27F124AF2E932AB468B79B5BAF96ACBDEA5D3B
```

Now that you know how to get expired certificates, you Script it out but be careful removing certificates even though they're expired they may be still used by the application.

Update:
Try This

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ |  Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -Match "Microsoft Intune MDM Device CA" -and $_.NotAfter -lt $today} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: thank you! The thumbprint for the same cert on our employees machines vary. Is there a way for me to tell the script to remove the cert with the name 'microsoft Intune MDM Device CA' that has already expired? i am trying to automate this as much as possible

Comment: Did you Try the new Code?